# perl inline replace with quotient

Tags: regex, perl, search, replace, inline

I have text lines of the form

```
F xxx.xxx
```

where F may be followed by an arbitrary amount of whitespace, followed by an arbitrary number of digits, optionally followed by a decimal and decimal digits. I want to find these numbers, divide them by a variable, and replace them.

My code mostly works, but I can't escape to actually calculate division on the numbers.

```
my $devisor = 60.0;
s/F\s*?(\d+(\.\d+)?)/"NEWF$1\/$divisor"/;
```

How can I search, calculate, and inline replace like this?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the '/e' modifier, the replacement part of `s///` will be treated as a Perl expression and evaluated. Also, you probably want another separator, so you can write division nicely without escaping. Your parens will only capture the decimal part, not the whole number. And finally, `devisor` is a misspelling.

Thus, you can write `s#F\s*(\d+(\/\d+)?)#$1/$divisor#e` (assuming you actually define `$divisor`).